# Scrape url with scrapy

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, scrapy

I am an data scraper using parsehub and content grabber but now want to learn scrapy for better extraction

I want to know the code to scrape the below url
 https://www.kimovil.com/de/wo-kaufen-xiaomi-redmi-note-8-pro-cn
 Please anyone can share me the code  for getting data in excel

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: import scrapy


class phoneSpider(scrapy.Spider):
  name ='kmovil'
  allowed_domains = ['kimovil.com/de/']
  start_urls =['https://www.kimovil.com/de/wo-kaufen-oneplus-2-3gb-16gb-cn']


def parse(self, response):
    pass

Comment: i made the above script but when crawl site not found but when i open link in browser it opens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally got the solution that only i had to change the user agent 
USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:74.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/74.0'